# If else in Mysql, how to declare constants in mySQL

Tags: mysql

SET @Name1 = 'YES';
If @Name1 ='YES' select 2 from dual else Select 3 from dual;

what is wrong in above statements

Comment: why is this tagged oracle?  is this in a stored procedure or function or not?

Comment: @ysth  I think mysql is owned by oracle maybe that's why both tags?

Comment: @BryanDellinger, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle: "Do NOT use this tag for other products owned by Oracle, such as Java and MySQL."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

show this:

```
SET @Name1 := "YES";
SELECT IF(@Name1 = "YES", 2,3) AS VAL;
```

You can also do the init in 1 statement like this:

```
SELECT IF(@Name1 = "YES", 2,3) AS VAL, field1, field2
FROM yourTable
CROSS JOIN(SET @Name1 := "YES") AS init
WHERE ......;
```

Comment: @supriya - i have add a sample

Comment: Can I use select statements instead of 2,3 ?
actually i have 2 different conditions.
if name1 is "yes" i have to return some fields and if name1 is not "yes" then return some different fields from table.

Comment: @supriya - yes, but can you give me a sample

Comment: This is the requirement
SET @Data := "YES";


SELECT IF(@AData = "YES", select RECORD from emp WHERE
ENDDATE>SYSDATE, SELECT record_id from emp where enddate<sysdate) AS VAL;

Comment: I was getting error when i added select statement.

Comment: @supriya - You can use thomething like this: SELECT record_id
 FROM emp
 WHERE IF(@AData = " YES", ENDDATE>SYSDATE , ENDDATE<SYSDATE)

Comment: Hi Bernd,


begin
SET @ADATA := "YES";
SELECT s FROM DUAL WHERE IF(ADATA = "YES", ENDDATE>SYSDATE , ENDDATE<SYSDATE)
end;

what is the syntax error in this? 
please help

Comment: @supriya - Hi, s, ENDDATE and SYSDATE are fields from your table, but DUAL is not a real table, its only a Dummy